# Find and delete column from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, where-clause

I'm trying to remove specific columns from an array:

```
data = array([[ 6,  3,  3],
              [ 7,  4, -1]])

target = array([[3]
                [-1]])
```

I want to find the index of the column within `data` which is identical to `target`, so that I can call:

```
np.delete(data, index, axis=1)
```

It looks like some combination of `all` and `where` might be the answer, but I just can't get it to work out.

Comment: A comma is missing in your example on the target variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mask `(data == target).all(axis=0)` will check for equality along the columns. You don't need to do anything with `where` or `delete`. Just use the mask as-is:

```
mask = (data == target).all(axis=0)
data = data[:, ~mask]
```

In fact, it may be faster to compute the mask of non-identical elements, since those are the ones you want to keep.

```
mask = (data != target).any(axis=0)
data = data[:, mask]
```

Comment: You hero! I knew it must be something straightforward but just couldn't see it! I guess there's not much in it either way but will probably opt for what you suggest. Thanks, will accept your answer when it's unlocked for me to do so in a few minutes :D.